# What is the relationship between diagonalizability and complete reducibility?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I've been wrestling with a certain paragraph in Dummit & Foote (pg 849) and would appreciate clarification.

> Let $G = \langle g \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and assume the field $F$ contains the $n$th roots of unity.  Let $V$ be an $F\langle g \rangle$-module. ...
>
> If the minimal polynomial of $g$ acting on $V$ does not have distinct roots (so $\text{char}(F) \mid n$), the Jordan canonical form of $g$ must have an elementary Jordan block of size $\,> 1$.  Since every linear transformation has a unique Jordan canonical form, $g$ cannot be represented by a diagonal matrix, **i.e., $V$ is not completely reducible.**  It follows from results on cyclic modules in Section 12.3 that the ($1$-dimensional) eigenspace of $g$ is any Jordan block of size $\,>1$ admits no $\langle g \rangle$-invariant complement, i.e., $V$ is reducible but not completely reducible.

I am unclear about the following points:

- (1) (Main concern) The boldface text gives me the impression that: If $V$ is completely reducible, then $g$ is diagonalizable -- possibly even iff.  However, I don't exactly see why this is true.

To my mind, saying that $g$ cannot be represented by a diagonal matrix tells me that $g$ is not a direct sum of $1$-dimensional sub-representations, but that's it.

- (2) I've read Section 12.3 on Jordan forms. I'm not completely clear on why the eigenspace of $g$ in any Jordan block of size $\,>1$ admits no $\langle g \rangle$-invariant complement.  And again, the wording makes it sound like the lack of a $\langle g \rangle$-invariant complement for this eigenspace somehow implies that $V$ is not completely reducible.

Thanks for your help and your patience.

**Edit:** A representation is *completely reducible* iff it is a direct sum of irreducible sub-representations.  (Similarly, a module is completely reducible iff is a a direct sum of irreducible submodules.)  I believe a synonym is "semisimple."

Comment: Could you add what completely reducible means?

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that for an algebraically closed field a commutative algebra the simple modules are necessarily 1-dimensional. Of course $F\langle g\rangle$ is a commutative algebra. For a proof, see e.g. [Proposition 3.2 in here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/coursework/424/FiniteGroups.pdf).

I sketch presented there: Let $V$ be a simple module, let $a\in A$ be an element of the algebra. Then for $b\in A$, and $v\in V$ an eigenvector for $a$ we have $a(bv)=b(av)=\lambda bv$. Thus the eigenspace of $a$ is stable under the action of $A$. Thus, since $V$ is simple, it must be the whole space. This holds for every $a$, so you can decompose $V$ into $1$-dimensional modules, since every subspace is stable under the action of $A$.

You can adapt the argument in the case you asked for, since your field contains the $n$-th root of unity.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was only aware of this "key observation" for $\mathbb{C}$. I was looking for a different sort of answer since Dummit & Foote don't mention this result until _after_ the paragraph I referenced. Obviously this is still very helpful.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, comment on (2)?

Comment: In fact... I think (2) is answered by Prop 5.2 in the notes -- assuming that result holds over fields other than $\mathbb{C}$ (does it?).  (These notes are very, very helpful, by the way!)

Comment: Prop. 5.2. (that direct sum of simples is the same as every submodule has a complement) holds in general over every field.